# Postgresql recovery setup

Tags: postgresql, restore

I have a standalone postgresql v13 server running with only a couple of 100gb databases. I am making daily dump based backups with commvault. My devs do not need PITR. I am using WALs only for performance. The crash recovery scenario I have imagined, is if a 1.server crashes I just reinstall another one and restore the backups, or 2. if I need to restore a DB to one day before I just restore the latest dump via Commvault. In the version 13 I see the grants are also restored via backup and I just need manually to create the role/users before restore. I have only worries about place on hdd on the WAL folder. If I restore the DBs and have existing WAL files, does pg_restore (via Commvault) rewrite them or I need to double the space inside the WAL Volume? I was thinking also to clean the WALs before dump restore via pg_archivebackup. Does this sound solid too you guys or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*I am using WALs only for performance*" makes no sense to me. You can't really not use WAL with Postgres. "*I was thinking also to clean the WALs before*" **never** mess around with the WAL directory yourself.

Comment: Why are you restoring the database?  Because someone dropped a table or ran an update they weren't supposed to, or because your server caught on fire and burned down?

Comment: TO a_horse_with_no_name I know I should not delete manually the wal file, so I am using pg_archive commands and they work just fine. @jjanes I am still not getting dev requests, but I guess yes, because someone deleted some data or dropped or similar.

Comment: Why are you archiving the WALs if you don't use PITR?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am archiving those files because of performance. I am actually deleteing older ones , older then 14 days, not to bloat the volume. Because of random seek I/O disk time, the WALs are faster then datafiles. Should not be the case on SSD disks, but I guess still the journal system-like WALs are much easier to read. So the key answer for WAL files is the performance, I guess.

Comment: "*I am archiving those files because of performance*" - that makes no sense to me. If you don't need PITR you don't need to archive the WAL segments. Why don't you simply turn off archive_mode? "*the WALs are faster then datafiles*" that has nothing to do with the performance of your queries. A query will never read from the WAL segments, so whether or not accessing WAL segments is faster than data files is irrelevant

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I guess you need to check out the PostgreSQL documentation. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-intro.html     Here you can read (I am not sure if the select queries are touching the wal logs, will search for this) that WAL logs give us page data consistency (fast crash recovery). Faster inserts and betterin fsync dealing with many small concurrent transactions. So I guess I am not loosing anything with WAL Logs. I just need to see how does this fit in my recovery/backup scenario (what was my inital question).

Comment: As I said: you can never work _without_ WAL. It's essentially for crash recovery. It is not used for read access - data consistency (MVCC) does not depend on WAL. And you can never turn off WAL generation. What you can turn off is WAL _archiving_ which determines how the system deals with WAL segments that are no longer needed. WAL archiving is essentially only required if you want PITR. If you have to use `pg_archive` it seems you have enabled WAL archiving which has nothing to do with performance at all.

Comment: Ok @a_horse_with_no_name a point taken. I have setup wal_archive to REPLICA, which I really need to have if I used PITR, maybe in future I will need PITR. WIth wal archive my backups will grow lineary as the size of WAL files grow. So could we go back to some thoughts on the initial question, the crash scenario with only making dumps and restoring them, if this should be enough ? I have tried to make a in-place-restore of the database with COmmvault PITR but this did not work fine. Classic dump restore worked. I guess when I have a roled already the privileges are included in the dump backups.

Comment: Also I guess there is a limitation of PITR with pg_restore, since I guess when you do a PITR on a cluster , you need to affect all of the databases and you cannot do each one, I am not saying it wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  At the end what do you think about the recovery scenario ?